# How I can bypass Symantec VIP authentication while running TestCafe automation test?

Tags: testing, automation, testcafe, two-factor-authentication, symantec

I am running TestCafe test automation.

We have Symantec 2-Factor authentication set while someone login using username&password.

I need to bypass OR validate this 2FA process using TestCafe.

I know the basic authentication we can do using TestCafe but not sure how I can do 2FA.

```
fixture `Login`    
    .httpAuth({
        username: userID,
        password: password,
    })
    .page(appUrl)
```

Answer (score 1):

You somehow need to programmatically get code from the NodeJS process that runs TestCafe tests. This is a difficult task. A more common approach is to disable or mock the 2FA process in test mode. It makes sense if you wish to test your Web application functionality and not Symantec 2FA.